# Android - How to allow the application to end a phone call

Tags: android

There is way to allow the application to make a phone call using

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(toDial)));
```

My question is, Is there any way to end the phone call through application, More specifically I need to try like end the call as soon as i get the call.

Cheers,
Vinayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54) ("reviewed and accepted") for the ability to programmatically reject a call on the standard framework. Of course, if you modify the framework you can do this sort of thing already: CyanogenMod includes a [modified Phone.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=539752) with a blacklist feature.

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible, as it would be a security violation.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on this question: Is there a way to create a secondary program that runs with the main phone program that would allow you to do another action either simultaneously as the call ends or immediately prior to the call ending.

Like, sending a pre-programmed text message to that person with an attachment and the the phone hangs up.  Is that possible?